# No bold formatting?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, markdown

It was brought to my attention [here](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/3190/close-reason-no-permanent-value?noredirect=1#comment6777_3190) that some more or less recent changes in how formatted text appears on my screen (which I dislike) might be a bug which only I can see. (I've posted some (now deleted) [example here](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/3200/dummy-post-if-youre-not-emrakul-please-ignore-will-be-deleted-soon?noredirect=1#comment6781_3200)).

For a while ( couple of weeks, not sure how long exactly. ) I do no longer get bold-formatted text. Or rather: ALL text is bold on my screen, regardless of my formatting tags.
I am using Windows 7 64-bit and Internet Explorer 11.0.9600 and what I'm seeing in *this* post on my screen is the following.

- normal text `normal text`
- **bold** text `**bold** text`
- *italic* text `*italic* text`

---

I get the following on my screen:

### [image: Example]

Is this a bug? Is it some setting?

Comment: Something on your end, I would say - [this is what I see](http://i.stack.imgur.com/EKMWi.png). IE 11 on Windows 8.1 here. Are you zoomed in/out? Any user stylesheets overriding the SE ones?

Comment: I'm using Windows 7 SP1 64bit and Internet Explorer 11.0.9600 and the bolding and italicizing that you included looks fine for me too.

Comment: Hmm. Zoom 100 and all on the default settings. Also no special plugins or stuff.  But looking at the site in Mozilla Firefox (just tried) gives me proper formatting as well. WTF? I don't even know how to start looking into this...

Comment: This is a resource issue and the question could be migrated to Superuser.